# Is there a way to have Vuforia and ARCore in the same app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia, arcore

We are currently developing an app for a student project, that we want to enable to use ARCore and ARKit on Android and iOS respectively and Vuforia as a fallback. After my project partner has already implemented ARKit and Vuforia in two separate scenes, I'm now trying to add ARKit.

But when trying to add both to the Android build under **Player Settings -> XR Settings**, I get the following message:

[image: Both ARCore and Vuforia XR Device support cannot be selected at the same time. Please select only one XR Device that will manage the Android device.]

We would like to be able to allow users to always be able to fall back to Vuforia, but use ARCore on compatible devices. Is there a way to have both in the project at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you would be able to do this if you're building Unity scenes into an android app built in Android studio or some other way. You would have a check for ARCore support on the device, and if that passes you would load a Unity scene that has ARCore support. If that does not pass you load another Unity scene that uses Vuforia. If you're working only in Unity like I am, I do not think it is possible. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Hey @HePa, I am wondering if my answer helped you out. Also, you could report this on the ARCore github and see if they have an answer for you.

Comment: Hi @nerk, I didn't end up testing your proposal, as we had to stick to Unity, because the project also needed to run on iOS and the additional work to go through Android Studio would've been to much. Additionally we decided to drop Vuforia altogether, thus solving our problem. But thank you anyway for answering! I'll mark you answer as correct, as it's assessment, that it's impossible in Unity is true

Comment: @HePa gotcha and thanks! Would you mind keeping me posted/let me know how you guys are doing ARCore/ARKit support in the same app in Unity? I would like to do the same but not sure how to do so yet. I haven't really looked into it but I'd love to hear what you guys are doing.

Comment: Depending on the device we either load a scene with ARCore or ARKit in it. Each of these scenes has an empty placeholder GameObject. Then we additivelly load a scene with our content. As we only want to place the content on a surface in the scene we pretty much just modified the example scenes from the respective libraries, place the placeholder like they do in those scenes (haven't looked at the ARKit example myself, just assuming that part) and then make our content the child of the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the vuforia settings and select the option "Do not use" the Ar core requirement, the app build will proceed normally and the app will work without errors

[image]